# Phrase for ending up paying for having done a favor

Tags: phrases

In my mother tongue (Gujarati) there are two phrases describing the adverse effects of doing a favor. What are their English equivalents, if any?

The phrases are:

- **આંગળી આપેને પ્હોંચો પકડે** (someone) is offered a finger and (they) grab the hand
- **ધરમ કરતા ધાડ પડી** Making a donation and getting robbed. ધરમ કરતા more often means performing religious ceremony, so another interpretation could be to get robbed while doing pooja.

Comment: Could you list the phrases in your language? That would be interesting.

Comment: @BobbiBennett I listed them in Gujarati but I don't know how it can be interesting for someone who does not read the script :)

Comment: The title is incorrect. You mean 'Pay for having done a favor' or so.

Comment: The context of 'a finger' in your culture is, I think, quite different from english. Perhaps it is closer to "Lift a finger to help, and (they) will take your whole hand."

Comment: @BobbiBennett I really don't think there is much context to "offering a finger", except maybe how a child holds on to en elder's finger while walking but it does not extend to holding the hand/palm. I think the phrase only relates to "hand is more then finger".

Comment: In Hungarian, the phrase "I offer my little  finger and he wants my whole hand" is used exactly in this form. I doubt the two languages are that closely related.

Comment: If someone were to offer me the finger, I would take it as a rude gesture. If someone were to suggest I pull their finger, I would expect a rude, flatulent, response (a fart).

Comment: In Italian, the phrase reads as "If you give him a hand, he'll take the arm". In same language, "Giving <someone> a hand" is the equivalent of "helping <someone>".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your first example has a direct equivalent:

> *Give them an inch and they'll take a mile*.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a direct equivalent (although it was the first thing I thought of too).  IME, it is used in more of an "allowing something" than in a doing a favor context.

Comment: I think the OP (Miserable Variable) has asked two questions. I also think this is the best answer for the first phrase.

Answer (score 26):

No good deed goes unpunished.

(A phrase I really dislike)

Comment: Indeed it is dislikeable, probably because it is absolute. But when used in a sentence -- "I don't want you to feel you are being punished for doing a good deed" -- it seems ok. Thanks.

Comment: *dislike* is not a compound that requires a hyphen.

Comment: No good answer shall go unupvoted +1.

Comment: @Kaz, thanks for pointing that out. I had wanted to write a -lot- about how I dislike that phrase, and got distracted.

Answer (score 10):

Another phrase (in addition to those mentioned) could be "biting the hand that feeds".

Here is a literal observation of this phenomenon: my girlfriend was trying to feed a neighbourhood stray cat, and the cat (being rather mean and nasty) scratched and tried to bite my girlfriend's hand.

Comment: Needs rephrasing -- the 'phenomenon' is not your gf but the cat. Change the word order without changing the meaning.

Comment: I read everything after "phenomenon is" as being the phenomenon and it sounded ok.

Answer (score 9):

**Camel's nose** is [a phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel%27s_nose) to describe the ill-effect that could result when doing a favour.

It is a reference to the famous Arab fable where an Arab offered a camel's head a place in the tent, but the camel slowly entered completely, thereby pushing the Arab himself out.

Comment: I don't think this phrase is common enough that it can be used without explanatory text.